# Как при проверки сделать пропуск значений которые уже находил?

Tags: javascript

```js
let arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '7', '8'];
for (let i in arr) {
  if (['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'].some(e => e === arr[i])) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    // из массива arr нужно взять ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
  }
}

console.log('---');

arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '7', '8'];
for (let i in arr) {
  if (['1', '3', '4'].some(e => e === arr[i])) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    // из массива arr нужно взять ['1', '2', '4']
  }
}
```

Comment: Цифры это для примера, значения могут быть разного вида

Comment: Просто вывод нужно вида запишите, что значит "нужно взять"? Не нужно их обрабатывать? Наоборот только их? Если обработка нужных здесь - console.log, то и запишите этот нужный вывод. А если у вас  `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']` и `['1', '3', '4']` и есть массивы, по которым надо пройти, то по ним и проходите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю зайти с обратной стороны и проходиться только по уникальным элементам.

```js
let arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '7', '8'];
let unique_arr = [...new Set(arr)];

for (let i in unique_arr) {
    console.log(unique_arr[i]);
}
```

Если смысл надо воспроизвести буквально, с проверкой пройденных элементов:

```js
let arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '6', '7', '8'];
let unique_arr = new Set();

for (let i in arr) {    
    if(!unique_arr.has(arr[i])){
        console.log(arr[i]);
    } 
    unique_arr.add(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, там просто массив по которому совпадения нужно искать

Comment: Будете вы пропускать пройденные или пройдетесь только по уникальным - какая разница?

Comment: Хорошо, думаю будет правильнее все таки оставить только уникальные, а по остальным уже делать разные проверки. Там просто скрипт огромный, это я его как мог упростил

Comment: В ваших примерах получается, что по массивам, в которых ищутся вхождения и надо собственно проходиться и все. То есть `for (let i in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']) {...}`. А зачем все остальное то?